# Crear un .zip con varios FileUpload Primefaces

Tags: java, aplicación-web, primefaces, java-ee

Necesito tener varios Drag and Drop y al final crear un .zip con todos los archivos que se hallan cargado en ellos.

Como puedo realizar esta accion ya que el listener fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" se usa en cada uno con su respectivo boton, yo necesito un solo boton y que recoga el de todos para despues crear el comprimido

Se que en uno solo puedo cargar varios archivos, pero no es lo que busco , necesito varios Drag and Drop

de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad no se si exista un control para hacer eso en primefaces. Pero yo te recomiendo usar la `API drag and drop de HTML5`. El capitulo 8 de [El Gran libro de HTML5, CSS3 y javascript](https://gutl.jovenclub.cu/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/El+gran+libro+de+HTML5+CSS3+y+Javascrip.pdf), explica como leer varios archivos de imágenes con drag an drop y lo podrías combinar con la `API File` del capitulo 12 para enviar los archivos al servidor, y ya comprimirlos ahi.